# How to display multiple checked items in multiselect combobox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

My Xaml code

```
<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                              x:Name="Stat"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              Width="247"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding OrderStatus,Mode=TwoWay}"                                                      
                         Text="{Binding StatusSelectedValue}"  

                          Height="26">

                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Description}"
                                       IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                       Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                                       Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

xaml.cs

//I would like to update the text displayed on my multi-select combobox when items are checked or unchecked

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = sender as CheckBox ;
        var r= selectedNode.IsChecked.Value;
```

//trying to obtain value of all checked items and concatenate it and display in combobox text something similar like below

```
            Stat.Text = String.Join(",",selectedItemValues.toArray());//this line of code is for example only for what i want to do
    }
```

any help either mvvm way or xaml.cs way is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void SetText()
    {

        if (this.SelectedItems != null)
        {
            StringBuilder displayText = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (ComboItem s in comboItemsCollection)
            {
                if (s.IsSelected == true && s.Title == Properties.Resources.CHECKALL)
                {
                    displayText = new StringBuilder();
                    displayText.Append("All");
                    break;
                }
                else if (s.IsSelected == true && s.Title != Properties.Resources.CHECKALL)
                {
                    displayText.Append(s.Title);
                    displayText.Append(',');
                }
            }
            this.Text = displayText.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' });
        }
        // set DefaultText if nothing else selected
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
        {
            this.Text = this.DefaultText;  
        }
    }
```

This is what i did. It display all the selected items with a ";" as a separator. If you have an "All" checkbox or you select all, it just display All. Of course i don't know what object you are using so i left my code as it is (you need to change the loop part, in particular the ComboItem part)

Note that this is a function (of course), so you can either add directly the code where you are doing the String.Join, or you call it